# jQuery datagrid plugin and jQuery inlineEdit plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery datagrid plugin to display my results in table. I have also used a jquery inlineEdit plugin. Both work fine. Until after pagination (say page 2) the inline plugin doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about either of the plugins but my guess it that when pagination occurs the table rows are removed and new ones are put in their place.  These new rows dont have the events assigned that are needed for the inline edit plugin.

to fix this you may have to have a onPagination callback that adds the inlineEdit events back to the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use the [jQuery live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - this will take care for the future rows added to the DOM automaticaly.